# How exactly does dynamic memory work with CLion?

Tags: c++, xcode, memory-management, clion

I started working on Xcode but then decided to use the CLion.
I have this class that has a pointer `char * buffer`. The constructor looks like this:

```
example::example (char input[], unsigned long len) {
    buffer = new char[len];
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        buffer[i] = input[i];
    }
    length = len;
}
```

The destructor is basically just `delete[] buffer`.

While running this on Xcode there were no issues, but when running the same code on CLion on the same machine I get this message:

```
Project(77633,0x7fffb5cb7340) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8a35400350: pointer being freed was not allocated

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Process finished with exit code 6
```

Although the code runs I still thought it was weird and after debugging I found it came from the destructor from my class. If I comment out the `delete[] buffer` part the message goes away.

So now I'm confused, I thought that you should **ALWAYS** delete the memory you allocated using `new`. Is that not the case?

Comment: Most likely, your `buffer` member has either already been deleted (are you following "the rule of three"?) or has become corrupted by something else in your code. You could also be using an `example` instance that has ceased to exist.

Comment: No, I was missing the copy constructor and that was it! I was passing an instance of the class as a parameter somewhere else. Implementing the copy constructor solved the issue. +1 for your help my friend.

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer so it can be voted as correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, neither CLion nor Xcode are compilers.
Under the hood, they run some configurable compiler.
Most probably gcc or clang of some version with some compilation flags
that are configurable too. So the first thing is to determine which compiler
is being used in each environment. Then it will be easier to answer the question.
Of course, a minimal complete and verifiable example is always needed.
By the way, did you make sure len is not 0? bad things happen when one tries to allocate 0 bytes ...

Comment: Good pickup on the 0 len value. Thank you!